# How to connect to an exist database on azure sql database (the schema "dbo") from android app

Tags: android, azure, azure-sql-database

How can I connect to an existing database on azure sql database (the schema "dbo") from an android app ?

I'm trying to connecting SQL Azure from my android application with jdbc and jtds but it doesn't work. Do you have another way or any other suggestions ?

Can I use azure mobile services ?

Comment: hey... you should see my answer below.

Comment: (if you meant the actual databse then you can just choose the database whilst creating a new mobile service) if you mean connecting to an existing table, I dont think you can do that, You would have to create a new mobile services instance and create a new table from within the mobile services webpage and then probably export and import the data from the existing table if it is possible

Answer (score 1):

Check the links below for how to connect to SQL DB from an Android mobile app.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started-data/

Answer (score 0):

You are working with **Android** . So, you need to go as:-

1. switch to  **Android Studio** , if you already did it then it's fine.
2. Use tutorials provided by **Microsoft Azure Mobile Services**.
3. Here is the **link to get started for Android** :- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started-data/